# Remove <br /> tags when window resized

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a funny issue, I'd like to remove the `<br>` under 760px width resolution. I've been using this which always worked, however it doesn't work on a new website I'm working on.

```
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 760) {
        $('p.nobreak br').replaceWith(' ');
        $('span.vert-align.centerone br').replaceWith(' ');
    }
});
```

The funny part is if instead of `< 760` I change by `> 760` (for higher resolution) and it does work! But I need this for `< 760`. Any advice guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code works, but only for the resolution the `window` is loaded at. You need to apply your logic in the `resize` event handler so that it reacts as the window size is changed. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var timer
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
           if ($(window).width() < 760){
               $('p.nobreak br, span.vert-align.centerone br').replaceWith(' ');
           }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Note however that a much better solution is to use CSS media queries to do this. It's faster, and also allows the effect of the `<br />` tags to be applied again if the window is made larger. Try this:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum
    <br />dolor sit amet
</p>
```

```css
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    p.nobreak br, 
    span.vert-align.centerone br {
        content: ' '
    }
    p.nobreak br:after, 
    span.vert-align.centerone br:after {
        content: ' '
    }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/98xu0ywv/) (drag the result panel size handles to see the effect in action)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use media queries to hide these elements instead of javascript?

Something like this for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
    p.nobreak br, span.vert-align.centerone br { display: none; }
}
```